# Retrieving the accepted answer date fails when the answer is deleted

Tags: bug, accepted-answer, deleted-answers

Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63303/how-do-i-know-when-the-last-outputdatareceived-has-arrived/64048#64048). Hovering the accepted answer check mark displays this text:

> loading when this answer was accepted...

The request to https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64048/accepted-answer-date fails with a HTTP 404 error.

Comment: That's one _old_ answer. This issue might be more related to the answer's age than the fact it's deleted.